# Is there any way to combine Postgresql's using with an additional clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose you have a table A and B:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
   id1
   id2
   creationDate
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE B (
   id1
   id2
   lastUsedDate
   ...
);
```

You would like to perform a select that joins these two tables together, however, one of the columns you would like to join on has a different name than the other column.

If you wanted to join on just the first two columns you are able to perform this query:

```
SELECT 
     id1
   , id2
   , ...
FROM A
JOIN B using(id1, id2)
;
```

However, if you also want to join on date, you are forced to perform this query:

```
SELECT 
     a.id1
   , a.id2
   , ...
FROM A a
JOIN B b ON 
        a.id1=b.id1
    AND a.id2=b.id2
    AND a.creationDate=b.lastUsedDate
;
```

This query is much more verbose, and if you omit `a.id1` and instead use `id1` postgres complains that `id1` is ambiguous, despite the fact that since you are using an `INNER JOIN` the column cannot be ambiguous.

Is there any way to combine the functionality of `using()` and an additional column that does not share the same name? Or are you forced to use the extra verbosity in the last example.

Comment: Add it to WHERE if it's not an Outer Join

Answer (score 3):

You could use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join to add equivalently named columns:

```
FROM A a JOIN
     (SELECT b.*, lastUsedDate as creationDate
      FROM B b
     ) b
     USING (id1, id2, creationDate)
```

Or add the extra condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
FROM A a JOIN
     B b
     USING (id1, id2)
WHERE a.creationDate = b.lastUsedDate
```

Comment: I was attempting to avoid including it in the where clause as with large queries I would like to have the joins and where logic separated.  
As for the subquery- will that have the same performance as the verbose example?  
Thanks for the answer! I suppose what I really wanted is the ability to use `using()` combined with `on` but sadly that isn't allowed.

Comment: @Eric . . . The `where` clause is possibly your best solution.  However, if you have complex `join` conditions, you need to be careful.  The columns come from *all* the preceding tables, not just the two that you might think are part of the `join`.  So, perhaps getting used to the old-fashioned method might be best.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a small number of columns in one of the tables, you can alias the columns so that the join columns have same names in each table. Example:

```
WITH tablea (a, b, c1) AS (
VALUES (1, 'x', 'y')
     , (2, 'x', 'z')
     , (3, 'y', 'z')
), tableb (a,b,c2) AS (
VALUES (1, 'x', 'y')
     , (2, 'x', 'z')
     , (3, 'y', 'z')
)
SELECT * 
FROM tablea AS t(a,b,c2)
JOIN tableb USING (a, b, c2)
```

*but, I would suggest putting the third condition in the `where` clause as [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) & [dnoeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527905/dnoeth) suggests*

Comment: Using an alias with column names is the best solution. It's safer than moving a condition to the `WHERE` clause (see also Gordon's comment)